# How to redirect single posts to canonical post?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

My wordpress is creating different URL's for every category I choose for my article.

**For example:**

Article Name: My Demo Article

Article Categories: Demo, New, what

Main Article Url: www.mywebsite.com/demo/my-demo-article/

But the same page can be access by adding other categories in URL.
e.g.

- www.mywebsite.com/new/my-demo-article/
- www.mywebsite.com/what/my-demo-article/

This is happening for almost all articles. Canonical System of my blog is working but I want to redirect these extra URL's to main article link. Also I want to know more about this issue. Like why this is happening? Why WordPress creating multiple URL's for all the categories? Is there any way to stop this?

**Please Note:**

I don't want to use `.htaccess`
I don't want to use any third party plugin.

Thank You...

Comment: WordPress auto adds a canonical meta tag.  If the solution would be simple with a plugin, what not use one? Lastly, this is a site to help developers - it would be appropriate for you to share what you've tried so far....  have you done any research? Have you seen [redirect_canonical[[https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical]?  Did you see [this question / answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19290/how-can-i-force-wordpress-to-redirect-to-canonical-permalinks)?  Or [this article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-canonicalization-guide/)?

Comment: I don't want to use plugin. I want to know how to do it myself.

Comment: That's fine.  Please acknowledge the rest of the questions in my comment, however.  I'm trying to help you....

Comment: Yes I am trying to understand how `redirect_canonical` works. Thank You for the answer cale_b :)